# rewrite www to non www doesn't work using two htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, https

I have two `.htaccess` file.

in root:(this file redirect to public folder)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /public/index.php/home/index [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

and in `public` folder I have:

```
# Disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Rewrite engine
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Turning on the rewrite engine is necessary for the following rules and features.
# FollowSymLinks must be enabled for this to work.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # If you installed CodeIgniter in a subfolder, you will need to
    # change the following line to match the subfolder you need.
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase
    # RewriteBase /

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com"
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to the front controller, index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

    # Ensure Authorization header is passed along
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
# X-XSS-Protection
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
</IfModule>
# X-Frame-Options
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
</IfModule>
# X-Content-Type nosniff
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
</IfModule>
# Disable server signature start
    ServerSignature Off
# Disable server signature end
```

I add this code for redirect `www` to none `www` in public folder `.htaccess` file:

```
# Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com"
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

but in action, my `www` not redirect to none `www`. how do can I fix this problem?

Comment: Comment out `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on` line and retest

Comment: Presumably, you should also be redirecting to `https://`. not `http://`?

Comment: @anubhava: Comment out? your mean is removing this line?

Comment: @MrWhite: I edited but, doesn't work.

Comment: @anubhava: I removed this line. now, `www` redirect to none `www` with this url:`/public/index.php/home/index`. my mean is redirect to this url ie: `https://domain/public/index.php/home/index`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> # Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com"
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
> ```

The issue here is that the `REQUEST_URI` server variable contains the full URL-path, including the `/public` subdirectory, so this will expose the `/public` subdirectory in the redirect.

*Aside:* Also, as mentioned in comments, unless you only want to perform the www to non-www redirect for HTTP-only requests then you should remove the first `RewriteCond` directive that checks the `HTTPS` server variable. I would also think you should be redirecting to `https://` here, not `http://`?

You need to either...

Capture the URL-path in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* and use this instead of the `REQUEST_URI` server variable (which is actually what you are doing in the preceding rule). For example:

```
# Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The captured URL-path (ie. `$1`) is relative to the current directory, so excludes the `/public` subdirectory. This also excludes the slash prefix.

However, without additional directives, the above will expose the `/index.php/home/index` URL (in the case of requests to the root).

OR, move this redirect to the root `.htaccess` file, which is preferable since it will naturally prevent the `/index.php/home/index` URL from being exposed. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect "www.example.com -> example.com"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Rewrite to /public subdirectory
RewriteRule ^$ public/index.php/home/index [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ public/$1 [L]
```

(The `<IfModule>` wrapper is not required.)

Note that you should first test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues. Only change to 301 (permanent) when you are sure it's working as intended.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: I've updated my answer, to address your homepage URL (ie. `/index.php/home/index`).